# How to organize code in text editors like dreamweaver and notepad++?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, notepad++

I wanted to know to to organize my html or any other code, with spaces from the border.
I mean what is the keyboard shortcut to do that, to add spaces to code to make it neater ?

and thanks

Comment: "what is the keyboard shortcut to do that, to add spaces to code to make it neater " - tab?!

Comment: It won't be the same keyboard shortcut in Dreamweaver as in Notepad++. Code auto-formatting is an application-dependent feature.

Answer (score 0):

> To organize the code

Mean you wish **to achieve better Readability**. So, for that **you have to Indent your Code** , In **dreamweaver**,I used <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+></kbd> to Indent the code, or refer these [key shortcuts of dreamweaver](http://cpaoffers.com/design/dw-shortcuts.php). For **Notepad++** ,Key shortcuts are [here](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm).
I refer you the following links, which might solve your query:

[Improving Code Readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550861/improving-code-readability)

Comment: @Felix thanks Felix for editing , however how you have done formating of the button in middle of text.

Comment: you can click edit to see the source. I just used the `<kbd>` tag :)