# Converting SPListItemCollection into DataTable

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have `SPListItemCollection` object.
I want to search an item in the collection. So I'm changing this collection into datatable .

```
 DataTable collection= operationLib.GetItems(spQuery).GetDataTable();
filter = collection.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<String>("id") == "someId");
```

So I want to know whether searching in collection using foreach loop is efficient or converting it to DataTable and then using Linq is more efficient?

Comment: Do you have performance problem or not?

Comment: Why can't you do the same LINQ operation in SPListItemCollection? What is the need to convert into datatable?

Comment: @OndrejTucny yes I was facing the proformance issue. Sorry for replying after such a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no reason for LINQ to be more efficient.
However, it is more [readable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=592616).
If you care much about performance do not use LINQ.
If on the other hand performance is not an issue then it is more readable.
Here is some more on [readabilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550861/improving-code-readability).