# How can I fix string matrix index problem?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to store name and address of persons in the form of 2d array, but when I run my code it accepts less values only. For example if I give the array 2 rows and 2 columns, it accepts only 3 values.

I've tried searching on other forums, couldn't get the proper answer.
I also changed the dimension values but it gives wrong result only.

```
import java.util.*;
class findme{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter the number of person: ");
        int per=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("enter the number of address: ");
        int addr=scan.nextInt();
        String addrs[][]=new String[per][addr];
        for(int i=0;i<per;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<addr;j++){
                addrs[i][j]=scan.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably due to your use of the `Scanner` API.

Comment: Please use the java naming convention of classes to start with uppercase. FindMe or Findme in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2):

You read 4 values but one is an empty line from when you press enter for `int addr=scan.nextInt();`

A quick fix is to read that empty line

```
import java.util.*;
class findme{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter the number of person: ");
        int per=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("enter the number of address: ");
        int addr=scan.nextInt();
--->        scan.nextLine();
        String addrs[][]=new String[per][addr];
        for(int i=0;i<per;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<addr;j++){
                addrs[i][j]=scan.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Or you can use `scanner.skip` [Skip newline character while reading from Scanner class](https://archie94.github.io/blogs/skip-newline-while-reading-from-scanner-class)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer here is how your code should look like:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of people: ");
    int iPeople = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the number of address: ");
    int iAdresses =scanner.nextInt();

    scanner.nextLine();

    String data[][] = new String[iPeople][iAdresses];
    for(int i=0; i < iPeople; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < iAdresses; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter %d address for person %d:%n", j + 1, i + 1);
            data[i][j] = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

And try to follow these conventions:

- [Use proper Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- Make your code more [readable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550920/5759072) by providing appropriate empty lines between lines you feel are too cluttered or belong to different groups based on what operation are they trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand why, the behavior of `nextLine` is explain here : [Java Scanner doesn't wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450524/java-scanner-doesnt-wait-for-user-input)

You can also replace `nextLine` by `next` to avoid this.